# How to choose the parent category that shows when using multiple custom categories

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy, terms

When a post is in two or most custom categories, how can I specify the parent category name that I want to show up?

An example is the custom post type "tour".  It is in the following categories:

- Alaska sailing
- Alaska
- Best selling tours

I want only "Alaska" category name to display and not others.

Comment: But how do you define which is a parent category and which is not?

Comment: What have you tried? What does your current code look like? A hierarchical taxonomy term can only have one parent-child relationship, so which term is "Alaska Sailing" a child of?

Comment: Well that is my question :) Both of them are parent

Comment: I have tried to get the parent category using get_the_category() function and it returns random category

Comment: "*Both of them are parent*" - I don't think that's possible. A term object can only have one parent. Please check carefully and verify.

Comment: Okay, once again... Tour (custom post type) "Alaska sailing" is under "Alaska" custom category and also under "Best selling tours" custom category. On tour edit page both of them are checked on the right widget area, so both of them are this tours categories. I want only to display "Alaska"! There is no parent category. Is this clear?

Comment: But the issue is which category to choose as the primary one for display. If both categories are set, how does the software know which to display? There is nothing by default that makes one category more important than another.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Maybe i should have asked that question! How can i set which category is parent?